# Angular Material Table not displaying data

Tags: angular, angular-material

What am I missing?  I verified that my API is returning data back however I can't get the data to display in my table.

Verified data:

```
<pre>{{ myData| json }}</pre>
```

Html

```
<div *ngIf="dataSource">
  <mat-table [dataSource]='dataSource'>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let df"> {{df.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="path">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Path </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let df"> {{df.path}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let df; columns: columnsToDisplay"></mat-row>

  </mat-table>
</div>
```

Typescript:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  columnsToDisplay = ['name', 'path'];
  myData: IMyData[];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<IMyData>(this.myData);

  constructor(private myDataService: MyDataService) { 
    console.log("IN CONSTRUCTOR");
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myDataService.getData()
    .subscribe(x => this.myData = x,
      error => console.log("Error (GetData) :: " + error)
    ); } 
}
```

EDIT: I wonder if it has to do with my interface:

Interface

```
export interface IMyData {
  id: string;
  path: string;
  date: Date;
  location: Geolocation;
  name: string;
  gizmos: string[];
}
```

Example Data:

```
[
  {
    "id": "9653a6b5-46d2-4941-8064-128c970c60b3",
    "path": "TestPath",
    "date": "2018-04-04T08:12:27.8366667",
    "location": "{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[102.0,0.5]}",
    "name": "TestName",
    "gizmos": [
      "AAAA",
      "BBBB",
      "CCCC"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in console.

Comment: No errors at all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First mistake is the incorrect data binding with single quotes instead of double quotes:

Change `<mat-table [dataSource]='dataSource'>`

To this: `<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">`

Second mistake is incorrect data source initialization. You should create the `MatTableDataSource` after fetching the data from the service.

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  columnsToDisplay = ['name', 'path'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<IMyData>;

  constructor(private myDataService: MyDataService) {   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myDataService.getData()
     .subscribe(data => this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data));
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that out and it still didn't work for me. I am guessing that grid rows are somehow being loaded before the data can actually populate the rows, in my case.

Comment: In my case, I made the second mistake. Followed your answer and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the datasource, not just the variable containing the data

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.myDataService.getData()
    .subscribe(x => 
      {
        this.myData = x;
        this.dataSource.data = x; //<=== update the datasource's data
      },
      error => console.log("Error (GetData) :: " + error)
    ); 
    }
```

and set correct binding

```
<mat-table [datasource]='dataSource'>
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I inherited from `MatTableDataSource` to create `MyDataSource`. **Without calling** after `this.data = someArray`

```
this.entitiesSubject.next(this.data as T[])
```

data where **not displayed**

### class MyDataSource

```
export class MyDataSource<T extends WhateverYouWant> extends MatTableDataSource<T> {

    private entitiesSubject = new BehaviorSubject<T[]>([]);


    loadDataSourceData(someArray: T[]){
        this.data = someArray //whenever it comes from an API asyncronously or not
        this.entitiesSubject.next(this.data as T[])// Otherwise data not displayed
    }

    public connect(): BehaviorSubject<T[]> {
        return this.entitiesSubject
    }

}//end Class
```